# Where can I find SQL language specification

Tags: sql, specifications

Is there an official SQL standard? I.e. I want to understand what type of expression is supported by SQL language and how this expression evaluated by server? What documents are using for implementation SQL based databases?

Comment: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt SQL-92

Comment: Yes, SQL is an [official ANSI / ISO standard (ISO/IEC-9075)](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ISO%2fIEC+9075-1%3a2011)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is an official SQL standard from the ISO/ANSI committee.

Some information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql

However the specification itself is not freely available. You might find some drafts of older specs in the internet if you search for it.

<strike>A nice explanation of the (yet a bit old) ANSI 99 standard is here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99-complete-really/</strike>

[Here](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/) is a compilation of at least the BNF syntax for various versions of the standard

Comment: I am simultaneously amused and annoyed that the SQL specification is freely available.  In practice, you really need to learn the API of the database your using, and that database is likely older than the first SQL specification.  And if you're writing a SQL based RDBMS from scratch, buying the spec is a small price to buy relative the overall cost of such a project.  Still, it'd be nice for SQL to be open source at this point.

Comment: The mariadb link is now dead.

Comment: @JustinBlank 
here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20151031013800/https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/

Comment: another good resource IMO:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language