# What are the technical differences between "select * from table_name" and "select a.* from table_name a"?

Tags: sql, db2

**This might be a basic question, but I can't find explanations after googling around.**

Anyway, a short background story. I have this table that I don't have the permission to alter on DB2:

```
other_field |  date_field  | time_field
---------------------------------------
     1      |    180101    |   101010
     2      |    180102    |   202020
     3      |    180103    |   303030
     4      |    180104    |   404040
```

**I tried to use:**

```
select *, concat(date_field, time_field) as TIME
from Table_Name
```

My expected result is **displaying** something like this:

```
other_field |  date_field  | time_field |     TIME
--------------------------------------------------------
     1      |    180101    |   101010   | 180101101010
     2      |    180102    |   102020   | 180102102020
     3      |    180103    |   103030   | 180103103030
     4      |    180104    |   104040   | 180104104040
```

But I can't use that query for some reason. It gave me an error `...Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FROM INTO` that basically said a comma (`,`) after `*` is invalid.

**Then I tried tweaking it a little into:**

```
select a.*, concat(a.date_field, a.time_field) as TIME
from Table_Name a
```

And it works!

I understand that `Table_Name a` are often used for joining tables, but I'm curious about the underlying mechanism.

What are the technical differences between using `Table_Name` and `Table_Name a`? And what is this `a` called?

Comment: `a` is called an alias.

Comment: @GSerg Yes, the first query works fine in SQL simulators, but somehow it didn't work in actual DB2.

So, `a` is not a virtual table?

Comment: The problem/solution part of your question is a Possible duplicate of [DB2 SQL Select All With Columns As](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50820397/11683); as for the *why* part, apparently it's because DB2 simply does not support it.

Comment: There is no difference if your RDBMS supports it. Forcing you to use an alias is fine, because `SELECT a.*` is better than `SELECT *`(at least you specify the table you want all columns from), even though using `*` is [a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: According to the ANSI SQL standard, a single `*` can't be combined with anything else in the select list.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for linking me to that question, but I'm more interested in the *why* part. If DB2 does not support it, then it would be enough explanation for me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I understand that `select *` would be bad for maintenance. Thank you for the advice & the link.

Comment: @WidiWidiyanto jarlh [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478140/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-select-from-table-name-and-selec#comment93826518_53478140) the why part too. The ANSI standard is [not freely available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21814101/11683); a search for ANSI SQL grammar gives e.g. https://ronsavage.github.io/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#query%20specification, where you can see that only `<qualified asterisk>` can be combined with other expressions on the `select` list.

Comment: Side note:  If you're actually dealing with date/time columns, and combining them, you would of course be much better off converting them to the proper types, and especially, replacing the current pair of columns with the proper `TIMESTAMP` type.  For any number of reasons, but the simplest is that it makes things much easier to query.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Actually, I use that query for Splunk which does not need "proper" TIMESTAMP since I can define my own timestamp format. And I don't have the permission to change datatype, actually.

Comment: @GSerg After reading the elaborate answer from Pallab, now I'm able to understand that comment. :D

Comment: @WidiWidiyanto - Can? Yes.  Should?  Maybe not.  For readability, if nothing else, using a standardized format (usually ISO-8601 based) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically there will be no difference between the op of
`SELECT * FROM TAB_NAME` and `SELECT a,* FROM TAB_NAME a`.

Here you are just specifying alias name.

But you can understand the difference when you will try to fetch another column with * from TAB_NAME.
That means if you want to gate data as bellow

```
SELECT *,COL_1,COL2... 
FROM TAB_NAME
```

or

```
SELECT *,CONCAT(...) 
FROM TAB_NAME
```

or anything with * you must have to specify the alias name.

But the question is why? Let me try to explain,

As you know here `SELECT *` means you are trying to select all columns. So, `*` means "all" and if you are putting `*` after `SELECT` clause that means you already have given a command to your system to select all by passing a special character and after that your system can only expect `FROM` clause instead of any other thing. Because you already told your system/database to select all then there would be nothing left to select and hence your system will always wait for `FROM` clause. So it will throw an error each and every time.

BUT now the question is, how the bellow query will work internally

```
SELECT a.*,COL_1,COL2... 
FROM TAB_NAME a
```

or

```
SELECT a.*,a.COL_1,a.COL2... 
FROM TAB_NAME a
```

or

```
SELECT a.*,CONCAT(c1,c2) 
FROM TAB_NAME a
```

or

```
SELECT a.*,CONCAT(a.c1,a.c2) 
FROM TAB_NAME a
```

or anything else like that.

Here your system will understand that you are trying to select all from table a that means you may select any other col/function etc from either table a or any other table. That's the reason why your system/database will allow you to insert other col/func also after a, if required or you can use from clause as well after `a.*`

Comment: The only reason why `select *, something_else` does not work is [because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478140/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-select-from-table-name-and-selec#comment93826518_53478140) this is the way it happens to be defined in the ANSI SQL grammar, and the DB2 version the OP uses leaves this behaviour unchanged. Some/many other RDBMS opt to extend this and allow selecting "everything and then some more", which makes perfect sense in the light of calculated columns and expressions that do not come from tables to begin with.

Comment: IIRC, `SELECT *, COL_1, COL2 FROM TAB_NAME` will return error for duplicate fields. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 (LUW) 11.1 support this syntax

```
create table Table_Name (
   other_field int not null primary key
,  date_field date not null
,  time_field time not null 
)
;
insert into Table_Name values 
    (1,'2018-01-01', '10.10.10')
,   (2,'2018-01-01', '20.20.20')
,   (3,'2018-01-01', '13.13.13')
,   (4,'2018-01-01', '14.14.14')
;
select *, timestamp(date_field, time_field) as TIME from Table_Name
;
```

which will return

```
 OTHER_FIELD    DATE_FIELD  TIME_FIELD  TIME
 -----------    ----------  ----------  ---------------------
           1    2018-01-01  10:10:10    2018-01-01 10:10:10.0
           2    2018-01-01  20:20:20    2018-01-01 20:20:20.0
           3    2018-01-01  13:13:13    2018-01-01 13:13:13.0
           4    2018-01-01  14:14:14    2018-01-01 14:14:14.0
```

BTW I took the liberty of using sensible data types for your example. Use `DATE1`, `TIME` and `TIMESAMP` (or `TIMESTAMP(0)`) for working with date and time values...

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I understand that the database I gave is not sensible, but I failed to mention that the database is not mine and I don't have permission to change anything.